# How to get pointed back button in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there anyway to get pointed back button like we have in iphone. Currently I am getting round button.

Also, any one has idea abt navigation bar in jQuery mobile. Whenever we are changing screen using navigation bar css is not getting applied.

Comment: I am looking for back button like this http://pessoal.org/blog/2009/02/03/iphone-sdk-customizing-back-button-title/

Comment: what do you mean by changing screen? Transition from one page to another page? What CSS is not applied? Active Class or any CSS? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Back Button:

You can try this:
http://taitems.tumblr.com/post/7240874402/ios-inspired-jquery-mobile-theme-jquery-mobile

But it will use a background picture instead of pure CSS backgrounds.

If you want to do it pure CSS, this will be tricky.

Start from here. I assign this to an empty div, which gives me a CSS only triangle, which I'm using for popup windows. You would have to find a way to turn this by 90 degrees, match border color to button background gradient and fiddle it into any of the JQM button styles.

Nice challenge :-)

```
.popover_triangle {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    border-color: transparent transparent black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 16px;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;        
    width: 0;
    }
```

If you manage to get it done, please post. There are a lot of people looking for it.